# Input columns as variables in PowerBI using Python scripts

Tags: python, powerbi

I am completely new using PowerBI although I already have some experience in python. There are certain plots that are not implemented in the program that I would like to make using a script (for example, violinplots), it works for me right now, but I find it extremely tedious to have to place the column from where I want to extract the data.

[image: "FamiliaDesc" and "Existencias" could be 2 variables obtained from power BI GUI]

"FamiliaDesc" and "Existencias" could be 2 variables obtained from power BI GUI.

Is there any way to get them and convert them into some variable, argument or whatever?
Thank you

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Ok, I have been investigating and I can assure almost 100% that the task that I have been trying cannot be done, in the end I have done it in python using seaborn and SQL.